# What are the options for returning a complex type from a view to a controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model named Order which has a property named Customer.  The Customer is a complex object with id, name, balance, etc.

When passing the Order object to a view, the view can access the Customer object and its data as expected.  However, when I post back to the Controller, the Order object is populated as expected, but the Customer object is null.

It would be nice if I could add a hidden field in the view for the Customer so it would be included in the post back, but I understand this works for single values not for complex types.

I suppose I could add all the Customer fields to the Order object, but before I do that, is there a way to include the complex object in the postback, or is there a better approach than consolidating the two objects into one by putting the individual Customer fields into the Order type?

Comment: You could add a hidden field for CustomerId, then use this to regenerate the Customer object server-side.

Comment: Why don't you create an EditorTemplate for the Customer model and include that in your Order view ?, like Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer).

Comment: If you're not changing any details for Customer, then you just need to pass CustomerId, and restore it in server side